# In which order do nested For Loops run?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, nested

```
 for(var i = 1; i<10; i++){
    
    for(var j = 1; j<10; j++){
    
    ss.getRange(j, j).setValue('Second Loop');
    }
    ss.getRange(i, i).setValue('First Loop');   
 }
```

In this example, I'm iterating through two For Loops. The results from the first loop should replace the result from the second loop because it comes after the second loop has set the values of the cell in the Google Sheet.

Yet this is the result that I get:

[image: The final value is from the Second Loop for all but the last.]

I sincerely appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the last iteration of i = 9 which would run like this

```
for(var j = 1; j<10; j++){
    ss.getRange(j, j).setValue('Second Loop');
}
ss.getRange(9, 9).setValue('First Loop');
```

So the last iteration of the enclosing loop will first write "Second Loop" to all diagonals and after that write "First Loop" to the field (9,9).

Nested loops run in the order in which the enclosing loop is run.

```
i=1: j=1 -> j=2 -> j=3 -> ... -> j=9
i=2: j=1 -> j=2 -> ... -> j=9
i=3: ...
```

So for each i, every j is iterated.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the response. I now understand where it is that I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

see when the outer loop runs last time , then the inner loop overwrites all the existing cells but the last one statement executes and prints `first loop`